# Rails CRUD - Destroy path always routes to the User show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, restful-url, restful-architecture

**My view is the users show page**

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel?', {:url => schedule_path,
                        :id => current_user.schedules[0].id,
                        :confirm => "are you sure?",
                        :method => :delete} %>
```

**Associations**

```
has_many :schedules
belongs_to :user
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :schedules 
resources :users
```

I don't match anything in routes.rb.  The parameters in the stack trace show `id` => `93`, which is what I want as I'm trying to destroy the schedule with id 93.  But it's routing to the show action of the user's controller when I want the destroy action of the schedule's controller.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: make sure you have include jquery and jquery_ujs in your <head> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `link_to 'Cancel?', schedule_path(current_user.schedules[0]), :confirm => "are you sure?", :method => :delete`

Comment: This fixed not only this problem but a few others as well - much obliged.