# Rails Guides: Getting Started 5.13 Deleting Articles: Confirmation Dialog Box WON'T Appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am currently trying to get Rails to run on my Windows 7 machine and I am having difficulty.  I am very new to Rails (inferred by my use of the Getting Started guide) and I am stuck on this:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-articles

Specifically the, you guessed it, confirmation dialog box.  It never appears and Rails just utilizes a SHOW route.

Now for the code:

app\assets\javascripts\application.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require_tree .
```

app\controllers\articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

app\views\articles\index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Articles</h1>
<%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>

  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

and app\views\layouts\application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

<!--%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %-->
```

Now in the command line, when I click the, "link_to," Destroy link, I get:

```
[2015-09-15 18:48:26] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. @ io_fillbuf - fd:10
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in 'eof?'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:80:in 'run'
    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in 'block in start_thread'
  Rendered C:/...
```

Note that everything seems normal after:

```
Rendered C:/
```

To fix this issue on my own, I have:

- Made sure SQLite is on my machine
- The SQLite gem is installed
- Active scripts are turned on for my web browser (Opera; based on
  Chromium)

I have followed every piece of advice I could from Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow, including:

Modifying index.html.erb with:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  post,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

or:

```
link_to 'Cancel?', schedule_path(current_user.schedules[0]), :confirm => "are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

or:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', { action: :destroy, id: post.id }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

or:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', [comment.post, comment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

- Making sure that because I am on Windows 7, that my CoffeeScript is
  version 1.8.0 and that I updated the Gemfile as such
- Making sure the gem, "jquery-rails," is included in the Gemfile file
- Using method: destroy instead of method: delete
- My rake routes look as they should.  One answer mentioned making sure
  `bin/rake routes` returned something normal and it does

Making sure the application.js file includes:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

(which you can see above that it does)

and nothing, **NOTHING**, has worked.

The only thing I have tried that has given me **ANY** success is replacing the `link_to` in index.html.erb with `button_to`.

But this doesn't produce a confirmation window.  It just performs a DESTROY.

I am very confused and I have spent many hours trying to get this to work.

I have found my answers from these links:

- [Rails CRUD - Destroy path always routes to the User show page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065717/rails-crud-destroy-path-always-routes-to-the-user-show-page)
- [Rails-4, ExecJS::ProgramError in Pages#welcome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241981/rails-4-execjsprogramerror-in-pageswelcome)
- [Rails, default.js is empty, and jquery and jquery_ujs not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850226/rails-default-js-is-empty-and-jquery-and-jquery-ujs-not-loaded)
- [Rails 4 link_to Destroy not working in Getting Started tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154916/rails-4-link-to-destroy-not-working-in-getting-started-tutorial)

I may be missing a few links and answers, so please feel free to link me to a thread you think I may have missed.

Thank you for reading this **MASSIVE** wall of text and I hope I can find a solution to my problem soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the layout is loading your javascript properly.

Try this. Hope it helps!

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using the application.html.erb that you gave me gave me another error: Sprockets::FileNotFound in Articles#index, which lead me to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239617/rails-4-sprocketsfilenotfound-in-welcomeindex and by removing //= require highcharts from my application.js, IT WORKED.  Thank you so much for your help!  The DESTROY works now just as it should and the Javascript pop-up works as well.  Thanks.

Comment: I am running rails ver. 4.2.5.1, ruby ver. 2.3.0p0, on a CentOS 6.6 Linux box, and I have *exactly* the same problem.  I *cannot* get the Destroy dialog to work, as per the "Getting Started with Ruby on Rails" Guide.  This is *very* annoying.  This is a common problem, with many posts, many solutions. I have tried them all.  "Destroy" uses "link_to" verb.  If changed to "button_to", it then works but WITHOUT THE DIALOG box.  My "application.html.erb" file same as is as shown here, still no "delete" method.  This is *not* a Windows/browser issue, same behaviour from an iPad, for example.